# Sending a message with file attachment of any type to server in android

Tags: android, android-intent, file-upload, android-file

I am working on an app which contains message sending module. Users can compose message as in email and send to other users.  I want to attach any type of file(.doc .txt image/audio/video) and send to server using

```
      receiver_id=12345&subject=testapi&msg=testmsg&attach_file=test.txt
```

I am doing this way

```
 private void attachFile() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null) {
        // it is device with samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = sIntent;
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                new Intent[] { intent });
    } else {
        chooserIntent = intent;
    }

    try {
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FILE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                   if (requestCode == PICK_FILE && resultCode ==getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

                        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                          Log.i("Attachment Path:", FilePath);
                    }
 }
```

I am getting the file path, but
1) how can I know the file is attached or not/ how to do attachment

2) how to send this file along with the message by specifying filename only (&attach_file=test.txt)?

I have seen many SO questions for sending attachment to email but not like this. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Quite confusing post. First you state that you have your own way of sending message and file. Then you are talking about sending an email with attachment. Please clarify. Keeping to your own way the line would become `"receiver_id=12345&subject=testapi&msg=testmsg&attach_file=" + FilePath;`.

Comment: Actually onClick of a button I have to open a file explorer and have to select from it. For that I have done this. @greenapps